# What is the use of <<<EOD in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

I am implementing node to PDF using Drupal and tcpdf. In such case I am suppose to use this `<<<EOD` tag. If I don't use it, it throws error. I can't exactly get the purpose of `<<<EOD`.

Could anybody please explain the concept of this?

```
$html = <<<EOD
        <tr>
          <td>TEST</td>
        </tr>
EOD;
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

That is not HTML, but PHP. It is called the HEREDOC string method, and is an alternative to using quotes for writing multiline strings.

The HTML in your example will be:

```
    <tr>
      <td>TEST</td>
    </tr>
```

Read the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) that explains it.

Comment: it's used also in perl :) don't forget that!

Comment: Word! +1. But since the question was tagged PHP, I thought this was appropriate.

Answer (score 39):

there are four types of strings available in php. They are single quotes ('), double quotes (") and Nowdoc `(<<<'EOD')` and heredoc`(<<<EOD)` strings

you can use both single quotes and double quotes inside heredoc string. Variables will be expanded just as double quotes.

nowdoc strings will not expand variables just like single quotes.

ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: What does the EOD by it self mean? And why does some use EOT?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Good question. It seems, that `EOD` means nothing special and that you can use virtually any label here, as long as opening and closing tags are similar. If you look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), into deeper examples (`Example #`), you'll find examples with `LABEL` (`<<<LABEL` + `LABEL;`) and `FOOBAR`. I also found `DEL` in some of my sources. So it seems, you are free to use anything, you want.

Comment: I always assumed it meant "End Of Data"

Comment: EOD = End Of Data, EOT = End of Text. Arbitrary labels.

Comment: Derived from traditional EOF (end-of-file) system signal. In traditional computing files were usually a tape content (hence EOT, end-of-tape or end-of-transmission) and therefore threated as streams (EOS was already "taken", so EOD, end-of-datastream) and piped from one call to another. Later on news groups and e-mail clients adapted this marker for end of typed text assuming it wouldn't appear in normal conversation. It did. Mainly in discussions about standards and DOC-like syntax. Some CLI e-mail clients still use it to this day. History of computing is beautiful.