# What does EOD acronym stand for?

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of <<<EOD in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924193/what-is-the-use-of-eod-in-php)

I know how to use it, I know it's used to mark Heredoc's syntax to easily print multiple lines of string, but what is full name of that EOD acronym (if it's acronym) ?
Only thing I heard is End Of Data, but I'm not sure if it's good.

Comment: See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924193/what-is-the-use-of-eod-in-php

Comment: Just to actually answer the question, it does literally it stand for End of Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOD isn't part of the Heredoc syntax. It's just used in their example.

```
$foo = <<<JAVASCRIPT
  alert('Hello!');
  alert('World!');
JAVASCRIPT;
```

This example would echo the javascript back to the user (or in other words, until the Token JAVASCRIPT is reached).

Comment: Hi Mike, took the liberty to clarify your answer a bit.

Comment: Using tokens like EOJAVASCRIPT, EOSQL & EOHTML has the nice effect of switching the syntax highlighting mode in vim as well

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, to bad I can't vote up your posts yet. It helped me to understand how Heredoc works.

Answer (score 1):

The heredoc identifier can be chosen at will:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
>
> [T]he identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore.

So it might just mean "End Of Data" as well as "Explosive Ordnance Disposal", but it doesn't really matter, it's jsut an identifier, and it could as well have been _Fo0b4R as any other (valid) identifier.

Comment: LOL "Explosive Ordnance Disposal". :)