# Magento 2 - Multiline content for static block installer

Tags: magento

What is best practice on Magento 2 for having multiline html in content? 
On Magento 1 if I remember right you would use some thing <<<'EOT'

```
$cmsBlockData = [
    'title' => "About Us",
    'identifier' => "aboutus",
    'content' => "
        <div class="intro-block" style="background-image: url({{view url='images/content/about-us-img1.jpg'}})">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
    ",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

actually there are four types of strings available in php. They are single quotes (`'`), double quotes (`"`) and Nowdoc (`<<<'EOD'`) and heredoc(`<<<EOD`) strings. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6924540/4956508)

You can use here document operator (<<<) then use a word like HTML, EOD, EOT or any string you want!

---

- Some handy notes when you wanna use heredoc : [here](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/php/php-here-document-heredoc-syntax-examples)
- Sample :

```
$html = <<<HTML
        <div class="intro-block" style="background-image: url({{view url='images/content/about-us-img1.jpg'}})">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
HTML;

        $cmsBlockData = [
            'title' => "About Us",
            'identifier' => "aboutus",
            'content' => $html
            ",
        ]
```